# How to avoid "jump" when removing a widget from QSrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt, qscrollarea

I have a QScollarea where widgets (rows) can be added or removed dynamically. I would like to avoid jumping around when removing a row (by adding blank space at the bottom if necessary).

For example: I have 5 rows and have scrolled/resized such that rows 2,3,4,5 are shown. Right now, when I remove row 4, rows 1,2,3,5 will be shown. However, I'd like to keep row 2 at the top and add some white space at the bottom so that rows 2,3,5 + a blank row are shown.

I have tried to play around with stretch but could not achieve this behaviour. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```py
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QScrollArea,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self._layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self._layout)
        for _ in range(5):
            self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.counter += 1
        add_button = QPushButton("+", None)
        add_button.clicked.connect(lambda _: self.add_row())
        remove_button = QPushButton("-", None)
        remove_button.clicked.connect(
            lambda _: self.remove_row_by_button(remove_button)
        )
        line_edit = QLineEdit(f"{self.counter}")

        row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        row_layout.addWidget(add_button, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        row_layout.addWidget(remove_button, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        row_layout.addWidget(line_edit, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        row_layout.addStretch()

        self._layout.addLayout(row_layout)

    def remove_row_by_button(self, remove_button):
        for i in range(self._layout.count()):
            row_layout = self._layout.itemAt(i)
            if row_layout.itemAt(1).widget() is remove_button:
                self.remove_row(i)
                return

    def remove_row(self, index):
        row_layout = self._layout.takeAt(index)
        QWidget().setLayout(row_layout)  # remove layout by setting it to another widget


class CustomScrollArea(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        widget = QWidget()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(CustomWidget())

        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWidget(widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    sa = CustomScrollArea()
    sa.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: I'm under the impression that your expectation is based on wrong premises. What you probably want is to keep the scroll area "extent", for which the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73641956/2001654) provided by Alexander might be fine as a basic workaround (while considering its important issues noted in my comment). But, then, what would happen if you then need to *add* another element, or, most importantly, you need to **insert** an element between the existing ones? I think that you should really clarify those aspects to you, and eventually explain *why* you need such a behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Well one really simple way to do this would be to add some fixed spacing using `layout.addSpacing` to the end of the layout each time a row is removed from the scroll area.

You will also want to make sure you properly delete the row in your `remove_row` method.

I made some inline notes where I made changes in the example below.

For example:

```py
    def remove_row_by_button(self, remove_button):

        # add button height plus layout gaps to get the size
        size = remove_button.height() + self._layout.spacing()

        for i in range(self._layout.count()):
            row_layout = self._layout.itemAt(i)
            if row_layout.itemAt(1).widget() is remove_button:
                self.remove_row(i)
                
                # add the spacing after removing the row
                self._layout.addSpacing(size)  

                return


    def remove_row(self, index):
        row_layout = self._layout.takeAt(index)
        row_layout.deleteLater()
```

Comment: This should also include the fact that `remove_row()` should eventually destroy the widget and **not** destroy the existing layout as did in the OP.

Comment: I literally didn't even notice that.  Thanks @musicamante

Comment: Actually, I was quite wrong: after reconsidering the OP code, that would "work" anyway, since the QBoxLayout implementation *does* set a null parent on child layout items, which results in destroying all elements of that layout item and the element is actually added as a child layout. That doesn't change much, though, as I think that the whole implementation is wrong in concept: I might understand the requirement (keeping the extent of the scroll area when removing an object), but the request is too vague and could be implemented in too many ways.

Comment: I agree about it being able to be implemented in a lot of ways.  As far as I am concerned I can only answer the question that they asked though, and this was the easiest implementation I could think of @musicamante

Comment: I am sorry about the vague requirements. I was trying to abstract my "real" problem into a simpler one (to be able to provide short code) and probably did not too well.

I actually have a search box and want to dynamically hide my widgets when searching. Your idea to simply add spacing whenever a widget is hidden (or removed, as in my original request) has helped me to solve that problem. When the widget is made visible again, the previously added spacing can simply be removed again.